# Cantidad de empleados por departamento, de aquellos que tienen dos empleados con su nombre,apellido y fecha de contratacion

Tags: sql

**tengo el código así **

```sql
Select count (*),department_id
From employees
Group by department_id
Having count  (*)>2
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.